# How to filter out characters in C programming with exceptions

Tags: c, floating-point, user-input

I am trying to write a C program that asks the user for an input and if the input is between a given `float` an output will appear. in this case if the input speed is 20.5 then the output would be you are in second gear. I want to filter out everything invalid input.

I already have some kind of a filter but it is not working well. if the in put is "afgegq" it will be filter and ask me again for input. But if it's 156FFAGFAE. it will be not filtered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        int versnelling[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        float speed = 0;
        printf("Please enter a speed: ");
        if (scanf("%f", &speed) != 1)
        {
            fputs("error: invalid input. Please enter a number\n",stderr);
            return 0;
        }

        if (0.0 < speed && speed < 10.0)
        {
            printf("The gear you are in is: %i\n", versnelling[0]);
        }
        else if (speed >= 10.0 && speed < 30.0)
        {
            printf("The gear you are in is: %i\n", versnelling[1]);
        }
        else if (speed >= 30.0 && speed < 60.0)
        {
            printf("The gear you are in is: %i\n", versnelling[2]);
        }
        else if (speed >= 60.0 && speed < 80.0)
        {
            printf("The gear you are in is: %i\n", versnelling[3]);
        }
        else if (speed >= 80.0 && speed <= 100)
        {
            printf("The gear you are in is: %i\n", versnelling[4]);
        }
        else if (speed > 100)
        {
            printf("I can not go faster then 100km/h \n");
        }
        else if (speed == 0)
        {
            printf("The gear you are in is: Neutral\n");
        }
        else if (speed < 0 && speed > -15)
        {
            printf("The gear you are in is: R\n");
        }
        else if (speed < -15)
        {
            printf("I can not go that fast in reverse\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I want it to filter out everything but the numbers and the letter Q. I need the letter Q because I want to create an average of the input(I will try to find out how later). but for know I need this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't keep undoing constructive edits - the spurious tags such as `C++` were removed for a good reason, and the broken code formatting has been fixed twice now.

Comment: Obtain the input with `fgets`. You can then examine it to see if it contains letters and act on them. Otherwise you can extract the `float` value with `sscanf` or `strtof`.

Comment: The car can never be in 1ste versnelling.

Comment: You write: _if the in put is "afgegq" it will be filter and ask me again for input._ This can't be true, after all, there's a `return 0` from `main()`.

Comment: Please explain _"with exceptions"_. There is no such thing as exceptions in C.

Comment: @Jabberwocky "There is no such thing as exceptions in C" - Not quite.  C does have _floating-point exceptions_ in its library,

Answer (score 0):

Well as long as you want scanf to give you a float, you will never get the letter Q in your user-input. Also you don't have any control on filtering the input.

What you can do is get a string from scanf, and filter it yourself. You can write a function that checks if the string consists of just the characters you want to accept, and call it in your your condition. Something like this:

```
char input[128];
if (scanf("%s", input) != 1 && check_input(input))
```

Of course you will have to convert the `input` to a float yourself (maybe using `atof()` or `strtof()`), and do something with the Q. But you will have more control over what input you accept.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle errant user input is to first read a *line* and then parse it for a `float` with `strtof()`.

```
    printf("Please enter a speed: ");
    fflush(stdout); // Insure prompt is printed first

    char buf[100];
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
      printf("End of file\n");
      return 0;
    }

    if (toupper((unsigned char) *buf) == 'Q') == NULL) {
      printf("Q detected\n");
      break;
    }

    char *endptr; // location to store end of parsing
    errno = 0;
    *f = strtof(buf, &endptr); 
    bool no_conversion = buf == endptr;

    // Allow trailing white-space
    while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) {
      endptr++;
    }

    if (no_conversion || *endptr) {
      fputs("error: invalid input. Please enter a number\n", stderr);
      continue; // No conversion or junk at the end
    }

    // Add additional tests if one wants to detect out-of-range (not shown)

    ....
```